# Cross Apply to Find All Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a table which will store current year dates , I am having a start date in that table  also. Is there any possibility to get all the dates between current and start date using CROSS APPLY.

```
Ex: 
Current_Year         Start_Date
2014-06-12           2011-01-01  
2014-04-12           2011-01-01 
2014-02-12           2011-01-01
2014-01-12           2011-01-01

I want result set like 

Year
2014-06-12           2011-01-01  
2014-04-12           2011-01-01 
2014-02-12           2011-01-01
2014-01-12           2011-01-01
2013-06-12           2011-01-01  
2013-04-12           2011-01-01 
2013-02-12           2011-01-01
2013-01-12           2011-01-01
2012-06-12           2011-01-01  
2012-04-12           2011-01-01 
2012-02-12           2011-01-01
2012-01-12           2011-01-01
2011-06-12           2011-01-01  
2011-04-12           2011-01-01 
2011-02-12           2011-01-01
2011-01-12           2011-01-01
```

Comment: and what does this `cross apply` look like?

Comment: But why is it important that you should use CROSS APPLY? this result can be achieved in other ways too.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give the desired results using CROSS APPLY:

```
WITH T AS 
(   SELECT  Current_Year = CAST(cy AS DATE), Start_Date = CAST(sd AS DATE)
    FROM    (VALUES
                ('2014-06-12', '2011-01-01'),
                ('2014-04-12', '2011-01-01'),
                ('2014-02-12', '2011-01-01'),
                ('2014-01-12', '2011-01-01')
            ) t (cy, sd)
)
SELECT  Current_Year = DATEADD(YEAR, - n.Number, t.Current_Year),
        t.Start_Date
FROM    T
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1
            FROM    sys.all_objects AS a
        ) AS n (Number)
WHERE   DATEADD(YEAR, - n.Number, t.Current_Year) > t.Start_Date;
```

But a CROSS JOIN would work equally well, and perhaps make more sense semantically, although the execution plan would end up being the same.

Comment: it is quite easy to do that with cte and #temp but due to my project requirements which holds bulk data cannot do that , i tried #temp and cte but the execution time is too high. So I want some mechanism which can do that woth cross apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TAB1 TABLE (CURRENT_YEAR DATE)
INSERT INTO @TAB1 VALUES('2014-06-12'),('2014-04-12'),('2014-02-12'),('2014-01-12')

DECLARE @TAB2 TABLE (CURRENT_YEAR DATE)
INSERT INTO @TAB2 VALUES('2011-01-01'),('2011-01-01'),('2011-01-01'),('2011-01-01')
```

SQL:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(YY,
        LU.[ROW] * (-1),A.CURRENT_YEAR) [YEAR],LU.CURRENT_YEAR [Static_YEAR]
FROM    @TAB1 A,
        (SELECT *,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_YEAR)) - 1 [ROW] FROM @TAB2) LU
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Current_Year
      FROM TableName) AS Current_Year
, (SELECT Start_Date
   FROM TableName) AS Start_Date
```

Cross Apply is used when you have function which returns a scalar value on right side of your join.